# Postgresql Query for display of records every 45 days

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has data of user_id and the timestamp they joined.
If I need to display the data month-wise I could just use:

```
select 
 count(user_id), 
 date_trunc('month',(to_timestamp(users.timestamp))::timestamp)::date
from 
 users 
group by 2
```

The date_trunc code allows to use 'second', 'day', 'week' etc. Hence I could get data grouped by such periods.
How do I get data grouped by "n-day" period say 45 days ?
Basically I need to display number users per 45 day period. 
Any suggestion or guidance appreciated!

Currently I get:

```
Date           Users
2015-03-01      47
2015-04-01      72
2015-05-01      123
2015-06-01      132
2015-07-01      136
2015-08-01      166
2015-09-01      129
2015-10-01      189
```

I would like the data to come in 45 days interval. Something like :-

```
Date           Users
2015-03-01      85
2015-04-15      157
2015-05-30      192
2015-07-14      229
2015-08-28      210
2015-10-12      294
```

UPDATE:

I used the following to get the output, but one problem remains. I'm getting values that are offset.

```
with
new_window as (
select
  generate_series as cohort
  , lag(generate_series, 1) over () as cohort_lag

from
  (
    select
      *
    from
      generate_series('2015-03-01'::date, '2016-01-01', '45 day')
  )
  t
)
select
  --cohort
  cohort_lag -- This worked. !!!
  , count(*)
from
  new_window
join users on
  user_timestamp <= cohort
  and user_timestamp > cohort_lag
group by 1
order by 1
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
Date           Users
2015-04-15      85
2015-05-30      157
2015-07-14      193
2015-08-28      225
2015-10-12      210
```

Basically The users displayed at 2015-03-01 should be the users between 2015-03-01 and 2015-04-15 and so on.

But I seem to be getting values of users upto a date. ie: upto 2015-04-15 users 85. which is not the results I want.
Any help here ?

Comment: can you pls show me image, what you want in result.

Comment: show sample input and its expected output

Comment: The Latest Edit solved my question. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this query :**

```
SELECT to_char(i::date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as date, 0 as users 
FROM generate_series('2015-03-01', '2015-11-30','45 day'::interval) as i;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
date        users
2015-03-01    0
2015-04-15    0
2015-05-30    0
2015-07-14    0
2015-08-28    0
2015-10-12    0
2015-11-26    0
```

Comment: If I use this series to generate my sequence. I get a cumulative sum of users rather than separate sum of users in the 45 day range.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a hot mess, and it might be better wrapped in a function where you could use some variables, but would something like this work?

```
with number_of_intervals as (
  select
    min (timestamp)::date as first_date,
    ceiling (extract (days from max (timestamp) - min (timestamp)) / 45)::int as num
  from users
),
intervals as (
  select
    generate_series(0, num - 1, 1) int_start,
    generate_series(1, num, 1) int_end
  from number_of_intervals
),
date_spans as (
  select
    n.first_date + 45 * i.int_start as interval_start,
    n.first_date + 45 * i.int_end as interval_end
  from
    number_of_intervals n
    cross join intervals i    
)
select
  d.interval_start, count (*) as user_count
from
  users u
  join date_spans d on
    u.timestamp >= d.interval_start and
    u.timestamp <  d.interval_end
group by
  d.interval_start
order by
  d.interval_start
```

With this sample data:

```
User Id     timestamp       derived range   count
1           3/1/2015        3/1-4/15    
2           3/26/2015       "   
3           4/4/2015        "   
4           4/6/2015        "               (4)
5           5/6/2015        4/16-5/30   
6           5/19/2015       "               (2)
7           6/16/2015       5/31-7/14   
8           6/27/2015       "   
9           7/9/2015        "               (3)
10          7/15/2015       7/15-8/28   
11          8/8/2015        "   
12          8/9/2015        "   
13          8/22/2015       "   
14          8/27/2015       "               (5)
```

Here is the output:

```
2015-03-01      4
2015-04-15      2
2015-05-30      3
2015-07-14      5
```